# How to disable the auto re-alignment behavior of fullPage.js when scrolling ends between the middle of two sections?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, fullpage.js

I don't know what is the best description for such issue to search for the answers. 
It looks to me like the [`fullPage.js`](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) has some build-in triggers that allows it to auto re-adjusting to align the section while scrolling ends in the middle part between two sections.

In normal scrolling mode, this behavior by default still exists, and would be quite annoying when user just want to scroll down precisely to view more text or want the page scroll to the wanted position.

Normalscrollbar mode url: http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/normalScroll.html
(when testing on device such as iPAD, when scroll ends between Dividing line, will trigger auto align. In desktop chrome or safari browser, this issue is not evident or hardly trigger at all.)

I've checked the resizeHandler in fullPage.js

```
//when resizing the site, we adjust the heights of the sections, slimScroll...
$(window).resize(resizeHandler);
```

But it seems not the exact trigger for that scroll readjust function.

I would like to disable auto align because it would conflict with normal scrolling behavior when users are scrolling the screen near the edge of two sections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the latest version of fullPage.js (2.4.7), I believe it has been solved as detailed [in this issue](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/799).

> It is happening because the address bar in the top changes its size when scrolling up or down and the resize event is fired, causing the plugin to try to readjust and fit the sections in the screen. (as you can see in the demo page by resizing the window)
>
> It seems iOS 8 was not acting in the same way, it was probably not firing the resize event.

Comment: Thanks so much, It's you who helped me again and again on fullPage.js related issues.